# Working with Parse and Angular Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, parse-platform

I am trying to retrieve information from parse based upon the objectID of a user entered in the textfield. I am using angular databiding, but it does seem to be working well.
below is the result shown:

[image]

Below is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js"></script>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>

    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>




</head>
<body ng-app="AuthApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
         userId: <input type="text" ng-model="userId" ng-blur="userIdChanged()"/>
            <div>{{addresss}}</div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the javascript for js/functions.js
:

```
Parse.initialize("id", "id");


var module = angular.module("AuthApp", []);

module.controller("MyCntrl", function($scope){

$scope.userIdChanged = function () {
    // now access $scope.userId here
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    query.get($scope.userId, {
      success: function(userInfo) {
        // The object was retrieved successfully.
        var address = userInfo.get("Address");
        $scope.address = 'addresss: ' + address;
      },
      error: function(object, error) {
        // The object was not retrieved successfully.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
      }
    }
  };

});
```

Update:
[image]

**Update 2:**
My console errors have been removed, but it does not seem to be working properly such that this is the updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.12.min.js"></script>

  <script src="angular.js"></script>


   <script>
   Parse.initialize("pWG7YizRnwxRjplGT9RSLoHtFItDtvmc2EK0YJAe", "C2qlan3y2PXi6nwVbACGT6fY3CTus8oVEvNo889u");


var module = angular.module("AuthApp", []);
module.controller("MyCntrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.userIdChanged = function () {
       // now access $scope.userId here
       var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

       query.get($scope.userId, {
           success: function(userInfo) {
               // The object was retrieved successfully.
               var address = userInfo.get("Address");
               $scope.address = 'address: ' + address;
           },
           error: function(object, error) {
               // The object was not retrieved successfully.
               // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
           }
       });
   };
});
</script>


</head>
<body ng-app="AuthApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
         userId: <input type="text" ng-model="userId" ng-blur="userIdChanged()"/>
            <div>{{address}}</div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Check your console for any errors. Also angular.js must be loaded before functions.js

Comment: you also have to respect the digest cycle.

Comment: thanks for your responses i have added the console log which shows some errors as a picture under the update section of my initial post.

Comment: can you yourself try and solve the basic errors

Comment: I tried and spent quite sometime trying to fix errors, but I have been unable to which is why I am kindly asking for assistance

Comment: Properly indenting your code will show you the problem

Comment: Also: `addresss` != `address`

Comment: have applied the changes but the problem persist. You can see my current status under the update section of my initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
{{addresss}}
```

should be:

```
{{address}}
```

because you're using `$scope.address`.

---

Loading animation idea:

```
$scope.userIdChanged = function () {
   $scope.loading = true;
   // now access $scope.userId here
   var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

   query.get($scope.userId, {
       success: function(userInfo) {
           // The object was retrieved successfully.
           var address = userInfo.get("Address");
           $scope.address = 'address: ' + address;
           $scope.loading = false;
       },
       error: function(object, error) {
           // The object was not retrieved successfully.
           // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
           $scope.loading = false;
       }
   });
};
```

And in the view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
     userId: <input type="text" ng-model="userId" ng-blur="userIdChanged()"/>
     <div>{{address}}</div>
     <div ng-show="loading">Loading data from the server...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. I have applied the changes but the problem persist. You can see my current status under the update section of my initial post

Comment: You're welcome. Are you sure that the request returns success and that the variable `userInfo` is in the format you expect? Why don't you log it so you can see what's going on. Also, you should handle the errors.

Comment: my problem did get resolved. and I thank you. I do notice that its bit slow for it occur (like there is lag between when someone enters the information in the textfield, the information gets populated. I wonder if I could integrate somekind of on screen loading

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. Yes, you can launch an animation or something at the same time you make the server call, and then stop the animation upon success (or error). See my update.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message from the console suggests it looks like you've got some broken javascript and mismatched closing parenthesis.

Try fixing your code:

```
Parse.initialize("id", "id");

var module = angular.module("AuthApp", []);
module.controller("MyCntrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.userIdChanged = function () {
       // now access $scope.userId here
       var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

       query.get($scope.userId, {
           success: function(userInfo) {
               // The object was retrieved successfully.
               var address = userInfo.get("Address");
               $scope.address = 'addresss: ' + address;
           },
           error: function(object, error) {
               // The object was not retrieved successfully.
               // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
           }
       }); // <!-- HERE you forgot to close the opening parenthesis of the query.get method
   };
});
```

Comment: Lesson for the OP. Use a decent JavaScript editor that highlights syntax problems like this. If you really don't want one, you can paste it into http://jsfiddle.net/10sd8and/ and press "tidy up code" which should make mismatched elements obvious

Comment: thank you for the suggestion and clarification. my console errors were removed, but this seems to have solve the problem half way. I have included an update version of my situation under update 2 section of my initial post

Comment: Did you check if the `success` or `error` callback is being executed? Also in your view you wrote `{{addresss}}` where you probably meant `{{address}}`.

Comment: my problem did get resolved. and I thank you. I do notice that its bit slow for it occur (like there is lag between when someone enters the information in the textfield, the information gets populated. I wonder if I could integrate somekind of on screen loading